# rackspace private containers via fog gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rackspace

I'm looking for someone who can give me some tips - or, ideally, knows where to find a step-by-step guide or something - for working with private rackspace containers (via temp URL) using Fog in a Rails app. I've got fairly far using just their documentation, but none of the temp URLs I generate seem to be valid (401 errors).

Anyone have any tips? I know this is fairly vague, but was hoping there might be a comprehensive guide out there or something - wasn't able to find one via googling around.

Thanks!

**EDITED**

So in response to a comment, I tried following the [directions from the getting started guide](https://developer.rackspace.com/docs/cloud-files/getting-started/?lang=ruby#get-object) exactly. When I go to the URL returned by the code below, I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. Any ideas?

```
require "fog"

@storage = Fog::Storage.new(:rackspace_username     => '{myUsername}',
                            :rackspace_api_key      => '{myAPIKey}',
                            :rackspace_region      => '{myRegion}',
                            :provider               => 'Rackspace')

directory = @storage.directories.get('{myContainer}')

directory.public = false
directory.save

file = directory.files.create(
  :key => 'somefile.txt',
  :body => 'Rackspace is awesome!'
)

account = @storage.account
account.meta_temp_url_key = '{myTempUrlKey}'
account.save

@storage = Fog::Storage.new(:rackspace_username     => '{myUsername}',
                            :rackspace_api_key      => '{myAPIKey}',
                            :rackspace_region       => '{myRegion}',
                            :rackspace_temp_url_key => '{myTempUrlKey}',
                            :provider               => 'Rackspace')

directory = @storage.directories.get('{myContainer}')

file = directory.files.get('somefile.txt')

temp_url = file.url(Time.now.to_i + 1000000)

puts temp_url
```

Comment: Can you share some of the code you have now for generating the temp URL? Also, is https://developer.rackspace.com/docs/cloud-files/getting-started/?lang=ruby#get-object the Rackspace documentation that you've already seen?

Comment: Edited the above to include that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED**

By getting rid of the directory, file, and temp_url variables at the end and instead using

```
@storage.get_object_https_url('{myContainer}', 'somefile.txt', Time.now + 60)
```

which was found in the [fog source here](https://github.com/fog/fog/blob/master/lib/fog/openstack/requests/storage/get_object_https_url.rb#L15).